# Scaling a scale

Tags: functions

I have a list of input values from 0 to 100.
Each value must be scaled to a short scale, that start from 20 to 80.

So:

```
0=>must be 20
100=> must be 80
```

and each numbers between 0 and 100 must take a scaled value into 20-80 range. What's the formula for scaling this input value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about $f(n)=0.6n+20$?.........

Comment: I found it perfect! How did you find it?

Comment: It is the [slope-intercept form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slope-intercept_form#Slope.E2.80.93intercept_form) of a line.  You wanted to reduce the range of $100$ to $60$, a factor $0.6$ and you wanted an intercept of $20$.